# grunt build done but not shows any page

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman-generator

grunt build it built my project successfully but I get blank page in browser with error file not found. but when I serve in development using grunt server it works fine.
I really don't understand what's wrong , I really don't know how to debug this issue.

please help

Comment: If you don't know where the problem lies, then you should simply employ the [rubber ducky method](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/) to try and identify what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my issue. posting the answer hope it help some one. if html5 mode activate in your project dist not work directly..It works after deploy thanks